# How do I upgrade Raspbian?

Tags: raspbian, operating-systems, kernel, firmware, update

I have my Raspberry Pi setup how I want, but I have an older version than what is currently available ([2012-10-28-wheezy-raspbian.zip](http://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads)). How do I upgrade the kernel, firmware, etc.?

I have upgraded some using:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
```

I believe my current Raspbian version is 2012-07-15 based on this:

```
[kevin@raspberrypi ~]$ more /boot/issue.txt
Raspberry Pi reference 2012-07-15 (armhf)
Generated using spindle, http://asbradbury.org/projects/spindle/, d2c1253, stage4-lxde-edu.qed
```

I am not sure what kernel version this is, though.

Comment: I think `/boot/issue.txt` is not modified since my `cat /boot/issue.txt` output is `Raspberry Pi reference 2012-09-18 (armhf)`. And, like you, I installed a version released before `2012-10-28`, probably `2012-09-19`... BTW, you should use `sudo apt-get upgrade` to install the new dependencies needed by the upgrades.

Comment: Now there is the Stretch version.  This link shows how to do the upgrade, but I'm going to wait until it is on NOOBS.  https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/71462/now-that-raspbian-stretch-has-been-released-should-jessie-users-rush-out-and-do

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I figured out which kernel version I installed by looking at `/proc/version`:

```
[kevin@raspberrypi tmp]$ more /proc/version
Linux version 3.2.27+ (dc4@dc4-arm-01) (gcc version 4.7.2 20120731 (prerelease) 
(crosstool-NG linaro-1.13.1+bzr2458 - Linaro GCC 2012.08) ) #250 PREEMPT Thu Oct
 18 19:03:02 BST 2012
```

I followed scruss' suggestion to use [rpi-update](https://github.com/Hexxeh/rpi-update). I deviated a little from the install instructions which suggests to install into /usr/bin, but I just put it in my user directory:

```
[kevin@raspberrypi ~]$ wget http://goo.gl/1BOfJ -O ./rpi-update && chmod +x rpi-update
```

After running `rpi-update`, I now have upgraded everything to 3.6.11.

```
[kevin@raspberrypi ~]$ more /proc/version
Linux version 3.6.11+ (dc4@dc4-arm-01) (gcc version 4.7.2 20120731 (prerelease) 
(crosstool-NG linaro-1.13.1+bzr2458 - Linaro GCC 2012.08) ) #340 PREEMPT Thu Dec
27 17:31:37 GMT 2012
```

Answer (score 7):

I don't use Raspian, but unless they've deviated significantly from Debian in their package management, `aptitude update` followed by `aptitude upgrade`, as you've done, should update the packages on the system. You could also try `aptitude dist-upgrade`.

I don't know if that will update the Kernel image or not, but I suspect that it will not. For the kernel, modules, and firmware, you'll probably want to download the latest binaries from GitHub: https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware. Just copy the contents of the `boot` directory onto your `/boot/` partition. You'll also need to copy the `modules` directory to `/lib` on your system. You'll need to reboot to get the new kernel running, of course.

Comment: [rpi-update](https://github.com/Hexxeh/rpi-update "rpi-update") is a much simpler way of updating the firmware on Raspbian.

Comment: I think we must have different definitions of "simpler", but that script does look...interesting.

Comment: The underlying problem is that the kernel to be booted needs to be located in a location unknown to the apt-get system.

Comment: rpi-update is part of the wheezy already. So sudo rpi-update is the easiest way to go.