# Keyboard incompatible with Raspbian

Tags: raspbian, keyboard

My Logitech K100 keyboard is not working with Raspbian. I first installed the NOOBS OS available at http://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads. After booting into NOOBS I installed Raspbian. But after rebooting my keyboard was not working. It didnt work in NOOBS either. I had to use my mouse. But my keyboard worked when I installed Arch Linux. I wish to use Raspbian and not Arch Linux. What should I do ?

Comment: If you SSH into the Pi and do an `lsusb` does it see the keyboard? Can you see it under `/sys/class/input/` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Keyboard works in NOOBS but not Raspbian](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/8382/keyboard-works-in-noobs-but-not-raspbian)

Answer (score 1):

Here are all of the verified Logitech keyboards:

```
Logitech
Comfort Wave 450, labeled 100 mA (M/N Y-U0001, P/N 820-001725, PID SC951C40001)
diNovo Mini wireless keyboard with media controls and clickpad 920-000586 (B)
diNovo Edge Keyboard, Windows edition, built-in TouchDisc track-pad, Bluetooth with USB mini-receiver 967685-0403 (B)
older model 867777-0403 may need dwc_otg.speed=1 added to cmdline.txt to avoid dropped/repeated keys and dropped mousepad taps/clicks (B)
after Raspbian dist-upgrade about 12/12/12, if /lib/udev/rules.d/97-bluetooth-hid2hci.rules exists and di Novo Edge fails to respond, edit tail of line after "# Logitech devices" in that file from c71[34bc] to c71[bc] to ignore c713 and c714 (do not wordwrap long line), then it works fine
Wii wireless keyboard KG-0802 (!)
C-BG17-Dual Wireless keyboard and mouse with wired USB receiver (B)
Deluxe 250 Keyboard
Internet 350 (M/N 967740-0403)
Internet Navigator Keyboard
MK120 wired keyboard and mouse
MK220 wireless keyboard and mouse
MK250 wireless keyboard and mouse (no hub needed)
MK260 wireless keyboard and mouse (no hub needed)
MK300 wireless keyboard and mouse
MK320 wireless keyboard and mouse [32]
MK350 wireless keyboard (using Unifying receiver)
MK520 wireless keyboard and mouse
MK550 wireless keyboard and mouse (B)
MX3200 wireless keyboard and mouse (B)
MX5000 Bluetooth keyboard and mouse (B) The Logitech Bluetooth dongle also does proprietary wireless so it works without Bluetooth drivers.
EX100 Cordless Desktop, Wireless Keyboard and Mouse (B)
EX110 Cordless Desktop, wireless keyboard and mouse (B)
C-SF17 Cordless Desktop Express, Wireless Keyboard and Mouse (B) PS/2 Interface. Tested using PS/2 to USB Banbridge CPA4002 Adapter
K120 Keyboard (B)
K200 Keyboard (B)
K230 Wireless Keyboard (Unifying receiver, no powered hub) (B)
K260 Wireless Keyboard & Mouse (Unifying receiver, no powered hub) (B)
K310 Washable Keyboard
K340 Wireless Keyboard (Unifying receiver, no powered hub) (B)
K350 Wireless Keyboard (B)
K400 wireless keyboard with touchpad - also listed under "problematic". Works for weeks with openelec and Raspbian without any problems. Worked out of the box - the on/off switch needs to be "on" for it to function correctly. Highly recommended if you are "working from the sofa". 
+1 on this, works out of the box with 2012-10-28-wheezy, no powered hub.
K520 Keyboard (B)
K700 Wireless Keyboard with Touchpad and unifying receiver
K750 Wireless Solar Keyboard (B) (Mac version works too. (B) )
LX 710 - works fine with receiver plugged directly into the Raspberry Pi (accompanying mouse works fine too).
S510 wireless keyboard and mouse (B)
Ultra-Flat Keyboard (M/N Y-BP62A P/N 820-000245 PID SY126UK)labelled 100 mA. OK direct into Model B Raspberry Pi.
G19 Gaming Keyboard, works fine with no external power. Illumination with external power. Powered hub in back of keyboard works too.
G15 Gaming keyboard, as long as you press the backlight button twice to turn off the backlight (it says below it dosen't work with backlight on.
V470 Bluetooth Laser Mouse
Keyboards and mice also together with Unifying receiver
```

from:http://elinux.org/RPi_VerifiedPeripherals

as you can see, the Logitech K100 keyboard is not a verified peripheral. It could be possible that Arch Linux has a driver that Raspbian is missing.

One thing you could try is updating your system:

1) ssh into Raspberry Pi from computer, for example:

```
ssh pi@192.168.1.100
```

2) then update your system:

```
aptitude update && aptitude upgrade
```

see: [How do I upgrade Raspbian?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/4020/how-do-i-upgrade-raspbian)

To be honest, your best bet is to just buy a different keyboard that is on the verified peripherals list. This way you know it will work on your Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Just to let others who are about to purchase the K230. It is now on the verified keyboards list: http://elinux.org/RPi_USB_Keyboards

Answer (score 0):

Initially I had the same problem with editing in VI editor raspberry pi (insert key,arrow keys etc..not working properly). I tried doing `dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` but it did not work for me.

I then installed vim editor (using `sudo apt-get vim`), surprisingly every key started working properly in both vim and vi editor from then on.

Answer (score 0):

Please note, that several Logitech Keyboards, like the G15 Series are consuming 300mA and above. The Raspberry PI does not support Power comsumption on these levels without an external USB-Hub.

Comment: That is not necessarily true. You can get at least 500 mA on the +/2/3 model with `max_usb_current=1` set in `config.txt` - if the Pi's power supply provides it (of course).